# Swift UIScrollView snap to subview width without pagingEnabled

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

How can i implement `UIScrollView` when swiping snap to its subviews width. I need it to behave like `pagingEnabled` but i cant enable paging because i need my entire view can be swipe to scroll. if i do `pagingEnable` its impossible because scrollview bounds will be change to subviews width.

is there any possible way to do this. 
[please check the image for more details](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ecm919f1x1ed6uc/screenshot.gif?dl=0)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{

  var navigationScroller: UIScrollView!
  var contentScroller: UIScrollView!
  var navContainer: UIView!
  var contentContainer: UIView!
  var selfWidth:CGFloat?
  var navigationLabels = ["EVENTS", "MEMBERS", "SECTORS", "ORGANIZATIONS", "SEARCH", "EVENTS", "MEMBERS"]
 private var buttonsTextFontAndSize: UIFont = UIFont(name:     "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 14)!
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    selfWidth = self.view.frame.width
    let frameWidth = self.view.frame.width
    let frameHeight = self.view.frame.height
    //let navscrollPosition = CGFloat( (frameWidth/2) - (75.0/2) )


    navContainer = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 75.0, frameWidth, 40.0))
    navContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0,  green:0.302,  blue:0.522, alpha:1)



    navigationScroller = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, frameWidth, 40.0))
    navigationScroller.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    navigationScroller.pagingEnabled = false
    navigationScroller.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    navigationScroller.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    navigationScroller.clipsToBounds = false
    navigationScroller.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    //navigationScroller.userInteractionEnabled = false
    //navigationScroller.

    addNavigationLabels(navigationScroller)
    self.view.addSubview(navContainer)
    navContainer.addSubview(navigationScroller)
    navigationScroller.contentSize = CGSize(width: 150.0 * CGFloat(navigationLabels.count),height: 40.0)
    navigationScroller.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 170.0, y:0.0)


    contentContainer = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 115.0, frameWidth, frameHeight-115.0))
    contentContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    contentScroller = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, frameWidth, frameHeight-115.0))
    contentScroller.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    contentScroller.pagingEnabled = true
    contentScroller.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    contentScroller.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    contentScroller.clipsToBounds = true
    contentScroller.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    //contentScroller.addSubview(navContainer)
    addContents(contentScroller)
    self.view.addSubview(contentContainer)
    contentContainer.addSubview(contentScroller)
    contentScroller.contentSize = CGSize(width: frameWidth * CGFloat(navigationLabels.count),
        height: frameHeight-115.0)
    //contentScroller.delegate = self
    navigationScroller.delegate = self



}

//MARK: -View Appeared function
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

// MARK: -Adding navigation labels fron navigation labels array
private func addNavigationLabels(navScrollView:UIScrollView){
    var buttonsXPosition: CGFloat = 0
    var buttonNumber = 0

    for navLabel in navigationLabels {
        var navButton: UIButton!
        let red = CGFloat(buttonNumber) - 0.9
        let frameWidth = self.view.frame.width
        navButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(buttonsXPosition, 0, frameWidth/3, 40.0))
        navButton.titleLabel!.font = buttonsTextFontAndSize
        navButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .Center

        navButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:red  ,  green:0.114,  blue:0.286, alpha:1)
        navButton.setTitle(navLabel, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        navButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        navScrollView.addSubview(navButton)

        buttonsXPosition = frameWidth/3 + buttonsXPosition
        buttonNumber++
    }
}

func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!){
    print("pressed")
}

// MARK: -Adding navigation labels fron navigation labels array
private func addContents(contentScroller:UIScrollView){
    var buttonsXPosition: CGFloat = 0
    var buttonNumber = 0
    let frameWidth = self.view.frame.width
    let frameHeight = self.view.frame.height
    for navLabel in navigationLabels {
        var navButton: UIButton!
        navButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(buttonsXPosition, 40.0, frameWidth, frameHeight-155))
        navButton.titleLabel!.font = buttonsTextFontAndSize
        navButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .Center
        navButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        navButton.setTitle(navLabel, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        contentScroller.addSubview(navButton)
        buttonsXPosition = frameWidth + buttonsXPosition
        buttonNumber++

    }
    } 
}
```

[app view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42zTS.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `UIScrollViewDelegate`'s method [`scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:) and modify the offset at it will finish decelerating to match the width that you wish.

Something like this:

```
class ScrollSample: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

        let targetOffset = targetContentOffset.memory.x
        // Round the offset to be a multiple of scrollview width
        let roundedOffset = round(targetOffset / scrollView.frame.width) * scrollView.frame.width
        targetContentOffset.memory = CGPoint(x: roundedOffset, y: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, its really great if you can post the code sample, please.